# Python webscraping error 403 + urlopen decode problem

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to extract website informations for the frist time so i'm scrupulously following a tutotial. I started my code as follow :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.unep.org/resources?f[0]=category%3A451&f[1]=category%3A452&f[2]=category%3A453&f[3]=category%3A454&f[4]=category%3A455&f[5]=type%3A55&keywords=&'

response = requests.get(url)
```

But when I've ran my code I had an error 403 (if I understood well it's because of website security)

Then I tried as solution the following code :

```
req = Request('https://www.unep.org/resources?f[0]=category%3A451&f[1]=category%3A452&f[2]=category%3A453&f[3]=category%3A454&f[4]=category%3A455&f[5]=type%3A55&keywords=&', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
rep = urlopen(req).read()
```

but when I continue my tutorial with the following code :

```
if response.ok:
print(response.text)
```

I had an error telling : AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'ok' and AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'text'

Then I tried "decode" :

```
response = rep.decode('utf-8')
```

But I got :
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ok' and AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

I'm a little lost, is there any way to solve this problem by obtaining the same result that my tutorial's code provide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think there is probably nothing wrong, maybe you are requesting to "aggressive". Could not reproduce the behavior - Following code gets all the headlines from that url.

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
url = 'https://www.unep.org/resources?f[0]=category%3A451&f[1]=category%3A452&f[2]=category%3A453&f[3]=category%3A454&f[4]=category%3A455&f[5]=type%3A55&keywords=&'
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(*[h.get_text() for h in BeautifulSoup(r.text).select('h5')],sep='\n')
```

**Output**

> Serving up sustainable food  Can coral reef restoration save one of
> the most vulnerable ecosystems to climate change? Remembrance Forests
> in Brazil: 200,000 trees for 200,000 COVID-19 victims State of Planet
> Podcast Implementation in nature-based solutions Finance for
> adaptation Planning for Adaptation As climate change hits harder,
> world must increase efforts to adapt Good news for Africa’s Great
> Green Wall Five things to know about desalination